# Ehcahe - RMI cache replication - newly added object not displayed in UI

Tags: ehcache

I am relatively new to `ehcache` and trying to implement caching in my application (Sample application). I am currently trying to use cache replication using RMI replication for some data objects. I have 2 instances of tomcat running on same machine and same application is deployed on both instances.  I have verified that on retrieving the object cache is hitting properly and it is improving performance.

But when I create a new object on first instance and try to retrieve in second instance (there's a page which lists all the objects), a newly added object is not displayed.

I can see that object is there in the cache of second instance. Also, it is confirmed in the logs also wherein I saw the following message

> 2012-07-03 17:06:41,471 [RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.100.105] DEBUG distribution.RMICachePeer  - RMICachePeer for cache com.mycompany.session.Session: remote put received. Element is: [ key = com.mycompany.session.Session#10, value=Item{version=0,freshTimestamp=5494027884412928, version=1, hitCount=0, CreationTime = 1341315402000, LastAccessTime = 1341315402000 ]

Has anybody seen this kind of behavior before, and can they help me to understand what could be wrong?

Below mentioned are the contents of my ehcache.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" >

<diskStore path="D:\\Cache1"/>

<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="peerDiscovery=automatic, multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1,         hostName=192.168.100.105, multicastGroupPort=4446, timeToLive=32"
/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory 
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="hostName=192.168.100.105, port=40001, socketTimeoutMillis=5000"
/>

<cache name="com.mycompany.session.Session"
      maxElementsInMemory="100"
      eternal="true"
      overflowToDisk="true">
      <cacheEventListenerFactory 
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
            properties="replicateAsynchronously=false
                       replicatePutsViaCopy=true,
                       replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true,
                       replicatePuts=true,
                       replicateUpdates=true,
                       replicateRemovals=true"/>
      <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory 
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"/>
</cache>

<defaultCache
       maxElementsInMemory="100"
       eternal="true"
       overflowToDisk="true"
/>

</ehcache>
```

Second instance of tomcat also has similar ehcache configuration except diskStore path is "D://Cache2" and peer listener port is 40002.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not setting port number in cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory. SHould we other way on server2 setting.

```
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="hostName=localhost, port=50001,socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>
```